# How can i cut the left part of the string with unknown legth? (with sql function)

Tags: sql, presto, sql-function

In the ETL process, I receive a varchar field, and the length (of the value) is changed from row to row.
I need to keep 5 symbols from the right side of the string.
It means that I need to cut the left side but I can't, due to the unknown length.

I've tried the `select substring('24:15:11',4, 5)`, but it doesn't help me, the string could be `'2019-05-01 22:15:11'`.

sql:

```
select substring('24:15:11',4, 5)
```

expected:

```
15:11
```

Comment: Hi! Have you tried the function RIGHT() ? not sure if it exists in your exact flavour of sql but I use it all the time in sql server.

Comment: @DavidSöderlund Is there a right() function in presto? I don't think so.

Comment: @DavidSöderlund - There doesn't appear to be a `RIGHT` function (https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/string), hence `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: I take it that your time segment *will* always be the same length (i.e. properly padded with lead zeroes (00:00:00)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`substr`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#substr). Negative starting position is interpreted as being relative to the end of the string.

```
select substr('24:15:11', -5)
```

Comment: Cool Thanks!   didn't know that I can use negative index

Comment: @Paul , the expected result in the question is minutes and seconds(the last five symbols).

Answer (score 3):

You can use length() to determine the 2nd argument of substr():

```
select substr('24:15:11', length('24:15:11') - 4, 5)
```

or simply:

```
select substr('24:15:11', length('24:15:11') - 4)
```

Read about preosto's [string functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/string).

Comment: Cool Thanks! didn't know that I can use negative index

Comment: @Terpsihora - he's not, really, he's deducting from the length. The second version is taking the length - 4 to the end of the string (i.e. there's no argument specified for number of characters, so EoS is assumed).

Comment: Well, linked docs for `substr` says *A negative starting position is interpreted as being relative to the end of the string.* - what's the point of using `length` then?